# Write path for HBase

Tags: hbase

I wanted to understand write path for HBase and got some very good articles on it so far:

```
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/06/hbase-write-path/
https://sematext.com/blog/2012/07/16/hbase-memstore-what-you-should-know/
```

However there is one question that remains unanswered (at least to me!).
As per my understanding, write comes directly to a `region server (RS)` and then it gets written to `WAL` and `Memstore` and eventually to `HFile`. Since `WAL` and `HFile` are on HFDS does it mean that the RS sends the data to `namenode` first and namenode then replicate it to other two RS. If my understanding is correct does it mean that if namenode is down all the writes to WAL will fail?

Comment: the namenode as hbase master is just a coordinator. the data transfer goes directly to the datanodes

Comment: So say if the replication factor is 3, does it mean that a write request will go to three region servers in parallel? If so, if the region server location gets cached by client how will namenode ever know where extra copies of new data is saved?

Comment: replication factor is for hdfs replication, not hbase. HBase has always only 1 region server writing data for a particular region. what happens is that hbase region server ask the namenode to create a file. the namenode will give you back 3 datanode location to write to. and hbase region server will write the data to the 3 datanodes

Comment: Thanks, it set me in right direction